# Unable to insert records in SQLite in android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I am inserting some data in the following way into my SQLite database :

```
                  Contact contactData = new Contact();
                  contactData.setContact_id("1111");//String.valueOf(id)
                 //contactData.setNickName(name);
                 // contactData.setPrimaryContact(primary);

                  HashMap<String, Contact> map =  new  HashMap<String, Contact>();
                  map.put("data", contactData);

                  long newId = datasource.createContact(map);                     
                  Log.e("insert Contact id :", String.valueOf(newId));
```

**and**

```
public long createContact(HashMap<String, Contact> queryValues) {
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

Contact val = (Contact) queryValues.get("data");

 values.put(  MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_CONTACT_ID,  val.getContact_id());
values.put(  MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_FIRST_NAME,  val.getFirstName());
values.put(  MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_LAST_NAME, val.getLastName());
values.put(  MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NICK_NAME, val.getNickName());
values.put(  MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_BIRTHDATE, val.getBirthDate());
values.put(  MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PRIMARY_CONTACT, val.getPrimaryContact());
values.put(  MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SECONDARY_CONTACT, val.getSecondaryContact());
values.put(  MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_EMAIL_ID, val.getEmailId());
values.put(  MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_STREET, val.getStreet());
values.put(  MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_CITY, val.getCity());
values.put(  MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ZIP_CODE, val.getZipCode());
values.put(  MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_COMPANY, val.getCompany());
values.put(  MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DESIGNATION,  val.getDesignation());
values.put(  MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_IS_FAVORITE,  val.getIsFavorite());
values.put(  MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_IS_BLOCKED,  val.getIsBloacked());    
values.put(  MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_IS_CREATED,  new Date().toString());    
values.put(  MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_IS_BLOCKED,  AESCryptography.getMd5(val.getFirstName()+" "+val.getLastName()+":"+val.getPrimaryContact()+":"+val.getEmailId()));   

long insertId = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.CONTACT_TABLE_NAME, null, values);
return insertId;
}
```

but i am getting the following error :

```
 02-06 17:13:18.539: E/SQLiteDatabase(8112): Error inserting lastName= contact_id=1111 primaryContact= street= designation= compnay= city= isCreated=Thu Feb 06 17:13:18 IST 2014 emailId= scondaryContact= nickName= isFavorite=0 zipCode= birthDate= firstName= isBloacked=�d�t�fVv�� ��
02-06 17:13:18.539: E/SQLiteDatabase(8112): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
02-06 17:13:18.539: E/SQLiteDatabase(8112):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_executeInsert(Native Method)
02-06 17:13:18.539: E/SQLiteDatabase(8112):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:113)
02-06 17:13:18.539: E/SQLiteDatabase(8112):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1718)
02-06 17:13:18.539: E/SQLiteDatabase(8112):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1591)
02-06 17:13:18.539: E/SQLiteDatabase(8112):     at com.ecosmob.contactpro.model.ContactDataSource.createContact(ContactDataSource.java:72)
02-06 17:13:18.539: E/SQLiteDatabase(8112):     at com.ecosmob.contactpro.service.ContactManagerService.onHandleIntent(ContactManagerService.java:88)
02-06 17:13:18.539: E/SQLiteDatabase(8112):     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
02-06 17:13:18.539: E/SQLiteDatabase(8112):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-06 17:13:18.539: E/SQLiteDatabase(8112):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-06 17:13:18.539: E/SQLiteDatabase(8112):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
02-06 17:13:18.539: E/insert Contact id :(8112): -1
```

What am I doing wrong?

**My table schema:**

```
  private static final String CONTACT_TABLE = "create table "
  + CONTACT_TABLE_NAME + "(" 
  + COLUMN_ID                   + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
  + COLUMN_CONTACT_ID           + " text not null, " 
  + COLUMN_FIRST_NAME           + " text not null,"
  + COLUMN_LAST_NAME            + " text not null,"
  + COLUMN_NICK_NAME            + " text not null,"
  + COLUMN_BIRTHDATE            + " text not null,"
  + COLUMN_PRIMARY_CONTACT      + " text not null,"
  + COLUMN_SECONDARY_CONTACT    + " text not null,"
  + COLUMN_EMAIL_ID             + " text not null,"
  + COLUMN_STREET               + " text not null,"
  + COLUMN_CITY                 + " text not null,"
  + COLUMN_ZIP_CODE             + " text not null,"
  + COLUMN_COMPANY              + " text not null,"
  + COLUMN_DESIGNATION          + " text not null,"
  + COLUMN_IS_FAVORITE          + " integer not null,"
  + COLUMN_IS_BLOCKED           + " integer not null,"
  + COLUMN_IS_CREATED           + " TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,"
  + COLUMN_CHECK_MD5            + " text not null"
  + ");";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've put in a whole bunch of `not null` statements. These mean you are required to put something there, or else the database will reject a new entry. I noticed you don't have a `COLUMN_CHECK_MD5` in your insert statement, and that is required in your schema. Look to see if there are others, and put something in there.

Comment: in this constructor `Contact contactData = new Contact();`, i'm assigning empty strings to all fields. so i may not required this.

Comment: The constructor has nothing to do with the sql. The create table is essentially the table constructor.

Comment: what i want to say is that i'm not inserting `null` in `ContentValues`. those values are empty string, which should be allowed.

Comment: They aren't in the insert, thus they are null.

Answer (score 2):

Your columns have `NOT NULL` constraints and 18 columns and you're trying to insert a value only to 15 columns as shown here:

```
Error inserting lastName= contact_id=1111 primaryContact= street= designation= compnay= city= emailId= scondaryContact= nickName=Bal Inquiry isFavorite=0 zipCode= birthDate= firstName= isBloacked=0
```

Either add a value to each column or remove the `NOT NULL` constraints from columns that can in fact be empty.

Comment: `_id` field is autoincrement so i have not included it. though i have tried including all other field at there. still i'm getting same error.

Comment: I counted 18 columns, out of which 16 are `NOT NULL` (and the id column implicitly). The insert contentvalues has 15 values. `COLUMN_CHECK_MD5` seems to be missing.

Comment: I means i have tried  doing so after your post. though i am getting the same. let me update this in my question.

Comment: Still no `COLUMN_CHECK_MD5` in contentvalues.